# Is it true that the first n prime numbers can be divided into two sets with sums differing at most by 1 for all n>1?

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, natural-numbers

Example ($n=6$):

$$2+5+13=20$$

$$3+7+11=21$$

Comment: Do you have any sources for this, or where you got this idea from?

Comment: Should be true for large enough $n$. However, unless I miss something,  that is not entirely obvious, so I do not understand the "close" vote.

Comment: For even $n$, must the two sets be the same size? What about odd $n$?

Comment: The most relevant entry I can find in the OEIS is http://oeis.org/A084139

Comment: this becomes a non paired prime subset sum problem. all pairs of twin primes can be added, such that the higher goes on the currently lower sum, and the lower goes on the higher sum.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I wonder how many people who voted to close can solve the problem (I can do it for large enough $n$, so it is solvable). That is certainly a more interesting question than the usual "integrate $x^2$ from $0$ to $3$" type, which seems to be flourishing, but I'm quite confused about the closing policy on MSE nowadays,,,

Comment: According to [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), context might qualify as the OP showing their work, or having some sort of background to the question. Whether the question should be closed if it has some intrinsic value to qualify as context is currently up for debate in the MSE community.

Comment: It is possible for the sum differing by at most 2 but not sure about the sum differing by at most 1

Comment: For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ consider the set of first $n$ prime numbers: $$P_n = \{p_1,\: p_2,\: p_3,\: \ldots, \:p_n\},$$
and the sum
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k.
$$
Hmm... It *looks like* **for any number $0\le x\le S_n$** (by exception of just six numbers $1$, $4$, $6$, $S_n-1$, $S_n-4$, $S_n-6$) the set $P_n$ can be divided into two subsets with sums $x$ and $S_n - x$.

The case of $x = \lfloor S_n/2\rfloor$ is covered by this (still) *conjecture* too.

Comment: @Oleg, combine with a strong enough variant of Bertrand's postulate for a proof by induction. IMO you deserve the rep for the major contribution, so unless you say otherwise I'll let you write the answer. (Also, I'm stuck with only a phone until Saturday).

Comment: Glad to see the question is re-opened. Actually, the question was also asked and answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34581). However if Oleg567 or Peter Taylor write down the proof of the generalized version of the statement, it would be great.

Comment: Thank you for the input so far.
@ Henry Lee: The idea came about by looking at subsets of primes. For all n<168, i.e. all primes up to 1000, the assumption is true. So, it seemed worthwhile to conjecture about all n.

Moreover, if the statement can be proven and if it is true for multiple other sequences as well then, in my eyes, the primes seem to progress in a highly structured way - no?
@ colt_browning: Thank you for your input and for pointing out dvitek’s comment.

Answer (score 2):

To get this question off the "Unanswered" list, here's a write-up of the proof sketched in comments. [Oleg567](/users/47993/oleg567) should get the credit for the key idea of the specific statement to prove; I've given him two weeks to write up an answer, but maybe he thought the link to MathOverflow was sufficient.

---

Notation:

- $p_n$ denotes the $n$th prime number
- $P_n = \{p_1, \ldots, p_n\}$ denotes the set of the first $n$ prime numbers
- $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i$ denotes the sum of the first $n$ prime numbers
- $\sigma_n = \{ \sum_{p \in s} p \mid s \subseteq P \}$ denotes the set of sums which are possible with a subset of the first $n$ prime numbers

The property we prove is that $\sigma_n = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, S_n\} \setminus \{1, 4, 6, S_n - 6, S_n - 4, S_n - 1\}$.

The proof is by induction. I'm going to tackle the inductive step first because then we'll see how many base cases we need. In other words, this is not a polished proof such as one might publish but a stream-of-consciousness to show the thought process.

#### Inductive step

Suppose that $n$ is sufficiently large (to be clarified) and that the property holds for all smaller values of $n$.

$\sigma_n = \sigma_{n-1} \cup \{ x + p_n \mid x \in \sigma_{n-1} \}$. The first part of that union gives us $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, S_{n-1}\} \setminus \{1, 4, 6, S_{n-1} - 6, S_{n-1} - 4, S_{n-1} - 1\}$, so we need to show that the second part of the union gives us $\{S_{n-1} - 6, S_{n-1} - 4, S_{n-1} - 1\}$ and $\{S_{n-1} + 1, S_{n-1} + 2, \ldots, S_n\} \setminus \{S_n - 6, S_n - 4, S_n - 1\}$; i.e. that $$\begin{eqnarray}
\{S_{n-1} - 6 - p_n, S_{n-1} - 4 - p_n, S_{n-1} - 1 - p_n\} \subseteq \sigma_{n-1} & \hspace{2em}\textrm{(1)} \\
\{S_{n-1} + 1, S_{n-1} + 2, \ldots, S_n\} \setminus \{S_n - 6, S_n - 4, S_n - 1\} \subseteq \{ x + p_n \mid x \in \sigma_{n-1} \} & \hspace{2em}\textrm{(2)}
\end{eqnarray}$$

If $S_{n-1} - 6 - p_n > 6$ and $S_{n-1} - 6 - p_n \not\in \{S_{n-1} - 6, S_{n-1} - 4, S_{n-1} - 1\}$ then the first number in $(1)$ is covered. Rephrased, we want $$
p_n < S_{n-1} - 12 \\
p_n \not \in \{ 0, -2, -5 \}$$

Similarly for the other two special cases we want

$$
p_n < S_{n-1} - 10 \\
p_n \not\in \{ 2, 0, -3 \} \\
p_n < S_{n-1} - 7 \\
p_n \not\in \{ 5, 3, 0 \} $$

$(2)$ can be rewritten as $$\forall {0 \le x < p_n, x \not\in \{1,4,6\}}: S_{n-1} + p_n - x \in \{ x + p_n \mid x \in \sigma_{n-1} \}$$ or $$\forall {0 \le x < p_n, x \not\in \{1,4,6\}}: S_{n-1} - x \in \sigma_{n-1}$$ which again boils down to $S_{n-1} - p_n - 1 > 6$ or $p_n < S_{n-1} - 7$.

So the inductive step is good as long as $$5 < p_n < S_{n-1} - 12$$

Here we apply [Bertrand's postulate](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate). The stronger the version taken, the simpler the proof will be, so we take Hanson's tight version that $\forall 2 \le x \in \mathbb{N}: \exists 3x < p < 4x: p \textrm{ is prime}$. If $p_k \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ then take $x = \frac{p_k + 2}{3}$ and $p_{k+1} < \frac{4p_k + 8}{3}$ or $p_k > \frac{3}{4}p_{k+1} - 2$; if $p_k \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ then take $x = \frac{p_k + 1}{3}$ and $p_{k+1} < \frac{4p_k + 4}{3}$ or $p_k > \frac34 p_{k+1} - 1$.

In either case $p_k \ge \frac{3}{4}p_{k+1} - 1$, so by induction $$p_{n-i} \ge \left(x \to \tfrac34 x - 1 \right)^i(p_n) = \left(\tfrac34\right)^i p_n - \frac{\left(\tfrac 34\right)^i - 1}{\tfrac 34 - 1} = \left(\tfrac34\right)^i (p_n + 4) - 4$$

Then $$S_{n-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(\tfrac34\right)^i (p_n + 4) - 4 = 3 (p_n + 4) \left(1 - \left(\tfrac34\right)^{n-1}\right) - 4(n-1)
$$
Thus certainly $S_{n-1} > p_n + 12$ if $$3 (p_n + 4) \left(1 - \left(\tfrac34\right)^{n-1}\right) - 4(n-1) > p_n + 12$$ i.e. if
$$p_n > \frac{4^n (n-1) + 4 \times 3^n}{2 \times 4^{n-1} - 3^n}$$

This is getting a bit long, so I'll abbreviate the next step. We show<sup>1</sup> that the right hand side grows by less than $2$ for $n > 5$, and since primes are at least $2$ apart and $$19 = p_8 > \frac{4^8 (8-1) + 4 \times 3^8}{2 \times 4^{8-1} - 3^8} = \frac{484996}{26207} \approx 18.51$$ we're good for $n \ge 8$.

#### Base cases

- $n = 1$: the subset sums of $\{2\}$ are $\{0, 2\}$, which is correct.
- $n = 2$: the subset sums of $\{2, 3\}$ are $\{0, 2, 3, 5\}$, which is correct.
- $n = 3$: the subset sums of $\{2, 3, 5\}$ are $\{0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10\}$, which is correct.
- $n = 4$: the subset sums of $\{2, 3, 5, 7\}$ are $\{0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 17\}$, which is correct.
- $n = 5$: the subset sums of $\{2, 3, 5, 7, 11\}$ are $\{0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 26, 28\}$, which is correct.
- $n = 6$: the subset sums of $\{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13\}$ are $\{0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36, 38, 39, 41\}$, which is correct.
- $n = 7$: the subset sums of $\{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17\}$ are $\{0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 55, 56, 58\}$, which is correct.

#### Postscript

You said in the comments that

> Moreover, if the statement can be proven and if it is true for multiple other sequences as well then, in my eyes, the primes seem to progress in a highly structured way - no?

Not really. I think that the weakest form of Bertrand's postulate would be enough, and even the form we use just says that if the primes grow exponentially then the exponent is less than $\tfrac43$. Much stronger bounds on their growth are known (it's not exponential: the $n$th prime is about $n \ln n$), but despite this for many purposes they can be treated as distributed randomly with a known distribution.

---

<sup>1</sup> $$\frac{4^{n+1} ({n+1}-1) + 4 \times 3^{n+1}}
{2 \times 4^{{n+1}-1} - 3^{n+1}} -
\frac{4^n (n-1) + 4 \times 3^n}
{2 \times 4^{n-1} - 3^n} = 2 - \frac{(n - 2) 12^n + 6 \times 9^n}{16^n - 3.5\times 12^n + 3\times 9^n} \\
$$